# Swift NSDate ISO 8601 format

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, iso8601

I am working on date formats in Swift and am trying to convert a string date to NSDate and an NSSate to string date (ISO 8601 format).

This is my code

```
let stringDate = "2016-05-14T09:30:00.000Z" // ISO 8601 format

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" // ISO 8601

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(stringDate)
print("Date = \(date)") // Output is 2016-05-14 16:30:00 +0000

// Again converting it date to string using stringFromDate
print("\(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!))") // 2016-05-14T09:30:00.000Z
```

I am trying to understand why I am getting NSDate in GMT format (adding 7 hours to time 09:30 to 16:30)?

If I convert that NSDate `date` variable to string, then I am getting the original string date. What is happening here?

Comment: Are you targeting macOS 10.12 or later? There is a new class `ISO8601DateFormatter` that might be helpful.

Comment: No. I am working on macOS 10.11.6 and iOS 9. 
I will check for this class `ISO8601DateFormatter`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [NSISO8601DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsiso8601dateformatter) or [ISO8601DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter) for Swift 3.0+

Answer (score 3):

Your format string was wrong. You indicate a literal `Z` instead of "Z as zulu time". Remove the single quotes:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

You should always specified the locale as `en_US_POSIX` [when parsing Internet time](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html). This is so commonly overlooked that Apple created the `ISO8601DateFormatter` class in [OS X v10.12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra) (Sierra).

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting iOS 11.0+ / [macOS v10.13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra)+ (High Sierra), you can simply use `ISO8601DateFormatter` with the `withInternetDateTime` and `withFractionalSeconds` options, like so:

```
let stringDate = "2016-05-14T09:30:00.000Z" // ISO 8601 format

let iso8601DateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
iso8601DateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
let date = iso8601DateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)

print("Date = \(date)") // Output is 2016-05-14 09:30:00 +0000
```

For working with `DateFormatter` on older systems, see [Apple Tech Note QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html):

> if you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the
>   locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed
>   format. In most cases the best locale to choose is "en_US_POSIX", a
>   locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results
>   regardless of both user and system preferences. "en_US_POSIX" is also
>   invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the
>   way it formats dates, "en_US" will change to reflect the new
>   behaviour, but "en_US_POSIX" will not), and between machines
>   ("en_US_POSIX" works the same on iOS as it does on OS X, and as it it
>   does on other platforms).

Here is a snippet of Swift 5, based on the sample code provided:

```
let stringDate = "2016-05-14T09:30:00.000Z" // ISO 8601 format

let rfc3339DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
rfc3339DateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
rfc3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'"
rfc3339DateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
let date = rfc3339DateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)

print("Date = \(date)") // Output is 2016-05-14 09:30:00 +0000
```